# IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8

Tags: python

I was trying to write a code to show the stock available(stock_level) for every items.
But i got an error as mentioned in the title.
im importing txt file into an array

```
code,description,stock_level,min_stock,max_stock,buying_price,selling_price
1,tukul,3,5,25,20.00,25.00
2,mouse,20,5,25,30.00,35.00
3,keyboard,2,5,25,30.00,35.00
4,headphone,20,5,25,100.00,105.00
5,monitor,1,5,25,150.00,155.00
6,cpu,20,5,25,700.00,705.00
7,casing,20,5,25,100.00,105.00
```

here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

list = np.zeros((7,8),dtype = str)
a = np.genfromtxt('stock.txt',delimiter = ',',dtype = str)
#print(a)

class stock:

    def __init__(self, code, description, stock_level, min_stock, max_stock, buying_price, selling_price):

        self.code = code
        self.description = description
        self.stock_level = stock_level

        self.min_stock = min_stock
        self.max_stock = max_stock
        self.buying_price = buying_price
        self.selling_price = selling_price

    def sell(stock):

        i = 0
        while i < 7:
            for r in a:
                r = 1
                for c in a:
                    print(a[r][1]," have ", a[r][2]," of stocks")
                    r += 1
            i += 1

disp = stock("","",0,0,0,0,0)
disp.display()
#disp.buy()
#disp.buy()
disp.sell()
```

the problem is in function sell()

here is the output that i got:

```
tukul  have  3  of stocks
mouse  have  20  of stocks
keyboard  have  2  of stocks
headphone  have  20  of stocks
monitor  have  1  of stocks
cpu  have  20  of stocks
casing  have  20  of stocks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OOP\Python\Kiosk\main.py", line 72, in <module>
    disp.sell()
  File "D:\OOP\Python\Kiosk\main.py", line 64, in sell
    print(a[r+1][1]," have ", a[r+1][2]," of stocks")
IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8
>>
```

i do got the result that i want which list of stock available for every items. But i dont know what cause the error

Comment: Read the error message, it's very straight forward. You can't query the 9th (human speak) item in a list of 8 items.

Comment: Thank you i solved it by using range function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programming languages use [Zero based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). This means that they begin counting at 0. For example, `list[0]` refers to the first item of `list`, and `list[7]` to the eighth. When you refer to `list[8]`, you are referencing the 9th element of a size-8 array, which raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your array start at the index 0
So if you try to access index 8 this is not possible you need an array of size 9 for that.
Your maximium index for an array of size 8 is 7.